# determinant of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

When we define the determinant of a linear transform $T:V\rightarrow V$ we consider it to be the determinant of the matrix we obtain as  a matrix representation of $T $ corresponding to a given basis say $B$ of $V$.But is the above definition  well defined i.e. if we consider another basis $B^1$ of $ V$ then we will get another representation of $T$ so how is this definition well defined?Is my question clear?If so,please give the required answer

Answer (score 2):

Given a linear operator $T:V\to V$ and two bases $\beta$ and $\beta^\prime$ of $V$ we have the identity
$$
[T]_\beta=P[T]_{\beta^\prime}P^{-1}
$$
where $P$ is the change of basis matrix from $\beta$ to $\beta^\prime$. It follows that $[T]_\beta$ and $[T]_{\beta^\prime}$ are similar matrices. Hence $[T]_\beta$ and $[T]_{\beta^\prime}$ have the same determinant.

Comment: Isn't this a circular argument? The characteristic polynomial *is* a determinant, after all! I would say that the essential thing is that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$; this is the property which shows that $\det(P^{-1})=1/\det(P)$ and hence that similar matrices have the same determinant.

Comment: Whether or not it is circular depends on how you think about the proof that similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial. If you use the statement "similar matrices have the same determinant and therefore have the same characteristic polynomial" and use this to conclude two similar matrices have the same determinant, then yes this logic is circular. If, however, you unwittingly prove that similar matrices have the same det while proving they have the same char poly, then I would view this argument as redundant but not circular. Either way it's probably best to edit.

Comment: Perhaps an even better perspective is to use the "determinant free" definition of the characteristic polynomial as discussed in Axler's famed "down with determinants." http://www.axler.net/DwD.pdf

Comment: True. If you introduce the characteristic polynomial of a linear transformation without even choosing a basis, then this whole question disappears. :-)